# Why does page scroll on load?

Tags: css

this has been a pain in my aardvark for some time now and I can't figure it out. For some reason all my product pages scroll to the middle of the page on load (I'm pretty sure it's the CSS not a script). Can anyone make a recommendation?

I've tried looking through the HTML and do not see any anchors in the mark up that would cause this. Here's a URL where you can see what I'm talking about:

https://fxmbaconsulting.com/services/mba-emba-recommendation-talking-points-writing-service/

Comment: There's  likely some javascript on there which is scrolling to the `.woocommerce-tabs` class or something similar. Try disabling all plugins and switching to a default theme & see if it still happens. There's far too many scripts loaded by that site to give you an answer without having a copy of it locally.

Comment: Also please provide an [mcve] when asking a question & review [ask]

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely to be a CSS issue. Take a look at that 'juxtapose' plugin and others tat are logging errors in console. Also take e look in that PHP error that happens when you load the page, maybe something isn't loading properly.

Comment: Thank you to Gabriel and everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the page scroll up when the page loads. Insert this between `<script></script>` tags on your page if you have JQuery libraries.

```
$(window).on('load', (e) => {  $(window).scrollTop(0) })
```

You can do the same with JavaScript if you are not using JQuery

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {  window.scroll(0, 0) })
```